# man pages: meaning of '2' in STAT(2)?

Tags: man, documentation

What's the significance of the number, like the `2` in `STAT(2)`, seen in man pages?

For example, `man 2 stat` yields a man page with `STAT(2)` at the top and a description that begins, `The stat() function...`, while `man stat` yields a man page with `STAT(1)` at the top and a description that begins, `The stat utility...`

I noticed the page for `STAT(1)` says `BSD General Commands Manual`, while that for `STAT(2)` says `BSD System Calls Manual`, so maybe the number is a code for the type of command?

Comment: Have you checked the manual page for the man command itself (i.e. `man man`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is a "section" there are several sections.  Usually

1 is General command
2 is System calls
3 is functions (for example in C)
4 is Special Files
5 is File Formats (think config files)
6 is misc.
7 is system commands

The reason is that a "term" may be in many sections. `ftp` is a command, could be a daemon and might have a config file.

So `stat(1)` is saying the general command stat, while `stat(2)` is saying the system call stat. It can be confusing. For normal usage usually you only see 1 and 5. 3, for example is filled with C function calls and such.

Comment: 8 is system commans, 7 is device, see man 7 intro

Comment: it's system dependent.

Answer (score 1):

In the "good old days", man pages were printed and came with the mainframe/mini computers (took all of them home to read at one point).  They came in volumes organized by usage: command, system command, library call, system call, file format, etc.  The `man(1)` page shows the volume names.  To view a page from a specific volume, you would put that on the command line before the manpage name: To see `stat(2)`, you would run `man 2 stat`.  Otherwise it takes the first volume that the name is found in, `stat(1)`.  To find if there are multiple entries in different volumes, you can use `apropos -e stat`.